# MySQL Workbench Model Cannot open document file git

Tags: mysql, git, newline, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

I am trying to open a MySQL workbench file (*.mwb) but getting the following error as per the 2nd screenshot...is there a way to restore this file?

> Cannot open document
>
> Cannot open document file: No Error

[image]

[image: MySQL Workbench open model error]

My files are in git but checking out older versions doesn't seem to work...I strongly believe it is something related to the line endings of the file as when I commit files I get the message from git along the lines of...

> CRLF will be replaced by LF in file x

Unfortunately I don't have any *.bak files in the same directory so can't restore it from that

I've also tried opening the file with 7zip and winrar, I can see an XML in there but get errors when trying to view it

My .gitattributes file is currently set as follows:

```
# Autodetect text files
* text=auto

# Force the following filetypes to have unix eols, so Windows does not break them
*.* text eol=lf

# (binary is a macro for -text -diff)
*.png binary
*.jpg binary
*.jpeg binary
*.gif binary
*.ico binary
```

I tried adding the following, deleting and checking out the file but it didn't work

```
*.mwb binary
```

Comment: Can you execute `git config core.autocrlf` from command line and post what this returns

Comment: It returns "false" for this project but in other git and non-git directories it is "true". I may have altered it this morning by running "git config core.autocrlf false" so not 100% sure of the value when I commited the most recent changes to the workbench file

Comment: Try to change it to true: `git config core.autocrlf true` and then do some whatever commit  and try then to open it.

Comment: The mwb file is a binary file (a zip actually) so git should never change anything in it. I consider this auto line break conversion feature of git a bad thing anyway. Nothing should ever change my files in any way, unless I do it explicitly.